# Can we use perf to analyze QEMU source?

Tags: debugging, qemu, perf

I want to analyze the QEMU source code and to do that I am planning to use perf. Essentially to identify execution hotspots. However, QEMU hangs and becomes unresponsive with an error. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Steps Followed

1. start QEMU guest os

```
sudo /opt/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-hda ./images/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img \
-hdb ./images/user-data.img \
-M q35,cxl=on \
-m 16G,maxmem=32G,slots=8 -smp 16 \
-enable-kvm \
-nographic \
-net nic \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::1811-:22
```

2. Ran perf on host to collect samples of process 49320 for analysis. 49320 is the process ID of the qemu process

```
 sudo /opt/perf/perf record -p 49320
```

3. QEMU Hangs with the following Error

```
BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: fffffe2ad7e28038
[  244.956759] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[  244.958401] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[  244.960029] PGD 47ffdf067 P4D 47ffdf067 PUD 0 
[  244.961481] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP PTI
[  244.962836] CPU: 5 PID: 990 Comm: ext4lazyinit Not tainted 6.5.0-rc2-00046-gccff6d117d8d #3
[  244.965390] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS rel-1.16.2-0-gea1b7a073390-prebuilt.qemu.org 04/01/2014
[  244.968785] RIP: 0010:__memcpy_flushcache+0x67/0x160
[  244.970373] Code: 48 8d 14 06 4c 8b 00 4c 8b 48 08 4c 8b 50 10 4c 8b 58 18 4c 0f c3 02 4c 0f c3 4a 08 4c 0f c3 52 10 4c 0f c3 5a 18 48 83 c0 20 <48> 39 c8 75 d1 48 83 e7 e0 83 e5 1f 4e 8d 64 27 20 4a 8d 1c 2f 48
[  244.975871] RSP: 0018:ffffb696809afba0 EFLAGS: 00010282
[  244.977515] RAX: ffffa05c80918b80
```

4. Host Kernel, Perf and QEMU version

   Note : Host kernel and perf are compiled from the same source

```
Dist : Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Kernel : 6.5.0
perf : 6.5.g2dde18cd1d8f
QEMU :  8.1.50
```

Comment: Host kernel / perf version, and QEMU version?

Comment: Host kernel : 6.5.0 , perf version : 6.5.g2dde18cd1d8f.  I compiled perf and linux kernel from the same source